# How to resolve JQuery Conflicts between 3 or more dependent versions of JQuery using .noConflict?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've found many other similar questions but this particular scenario is somewhat unique to the more typical ones to which the prior questions are applicable.

My understanding and the normal approach I use to resolve conflicts between 2 versions of JQuery are as follows in this example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Static/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-ui 1.12.1.custom/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var JQuery_1_12_1 = $.noConflict(true);
    $JQuery_1_12_1(document).ready(function () {

            // Code dependent on JQuery 1.12.1 can safely execute here without 
            // conflicting with version 1.3.2
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
            // Code executed within this block will use 1.3.2
</script>
```

Alternatively, I could have duplicated the approach implemented to define the noConflict variable for 1.12.1 for 1.3.2 and the result would have been the same.

The problem I'm having difficulty in resolving is that I'm confronted with a situation I previously haven't had to deal with where there are linked library dependencies that need to be combined together in a noConflict manner.

Here is the current situation:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Static/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" ></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-ui 1.12.1.custom/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var JQuery_1_12_1 = $.noConflict(true);
    $JQuery_1_12_1(document).ready(function () {

            // Code dependent on JQuery 1.12.1 can safely execute here without 
            // conflicting with version 1.3.2 but do to the lack of the dependent version this code will always break
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
            // Code executed within this block will use 1.3.2
</script>
```

As you can note, there is an inter-dependency between jquery-ui.js and jquery.js and due to this inter-dependency the $JQuery_1_12_1 variable cannot be applicable to both.

Alternatively, creating a separate noConflict variable for the jquery-ui.js library would require it to be placed within the context of a separate script tag which would essentially break the dependency and the code won't function correctly.

How can this problem be resolved?

I have also tried using the same versions of one of the JQuery libraries to alleviate the conflicts but they each have a unique set of features that don't crossover. So only one version will work per required application within the code.

Comment: Why are you even using so many versions of jQuery? 1.3.2 is *massively* out of date. Almost 10 years in fact. I'd suggest you spend the time unifying your codebase to a single instance of jQuery instead of coming up with a band-aid solution to enable multiple versions

Comment: Preaching to the choir here :-) I am simply trying to work with the hand I've been dealt. I did say that I tried consolidation under 1 version but it doesn't work due to the outdated version being tightly integrated with the code. If the answer is it can't be done... I'll accept that

Comment: @T.J.Crowder point noted and corrected. thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First**: Don't use multiple versions of jQuery. It bloats and complicates your page. Use an up-to-date version of jQuery and, if you have plugins that don't work with that up-to-date version, update them so they do (and ideally send a pull-request back to the plugin's repo if it has one), or use something that's actively maintained instead.

---

Now, if for some reason you can't do that:

Any half-decent jQuery plugin uses the `jQuery` variable's value *as of when the plugin is loaded*, by doing something like this:

```
(function($) {
    // Plugin code
})(jQuery);
```

If you load a different version of jQuery afterward, the plugin still uses the earlier one because it captured the value of `jQuery` as of when it loaded.

So load your plugins for a given jQuery version immediately after loading that version of jQuery.

Then: Do the same for your *own* code.

```
<script src="../Static/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" ></script>
<script src="../plugin/that/needs/version/132.js"></script>
<script src="../your/code/that/needs/version/132.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-ui 1.12.1.custom/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="../your/code/that/needs/what/jQueryUI/is/using.js"></script>
```

...where your script code does the same thing a well-behaved plugin does:

```
(function($) {
    // Use $ here
})(jQuery);
```

If you have code that *(shudders)* needs to use *both* versions of jQuery, capture each version in a variable:

```
<script src="../Static/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" ></script>
<script src="../plugin/that/needs/version/132.js"></script>
<script>
var jQuery_v132 = jQuery;
</script>
<script src="../your/code/that/needs/version/132.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-ui 1.12.1.custom/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
var jQuery_whatever = jQuery;
</script>
<script src="../your/code/that/needs/what/jQueryUI/is/using.js"></script>
<script src="../your/code/using/both.js"></script>
```

...where your code using both uses `jQuery_v132` or `jQuery_whatever` as appropriate.

(I've used "whatever" because I have no idea what version of jQuery your `jquery-ui 1.12.1.custom/jquery.js` file is, but it's unlikely to be jQuery 1.12.1.)

Comment: I agree totally on your very first point but my options in this particular situation are very limited. Aside from attempting to find a way to make this work with minimal code changes to the existing app.. the only other alternative would be to re-write many areas of the application coding with a more up-to-date version of the library. This app in my opinion simply doesn't justify the overhaul. I'll give your optional recommendations for worse case a try and will take away the wisdom of recommendations.

Comment: @Mark - Hope it goes well!